# Where is the best place to suggest features / ask for little quality of life improvments?

Tags: system

I have been using eOS as my everyday OS for a couple of weeks now and noticed multiple possible small additions, of which I think would make a great improvement while not being too hard to implement(?).

So my question is where would be the place to make these kind of suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This is the place for request/wish and bug reporting: https://github.com/elementary

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the other answer, GitHub is the correct place to raise feature requests. Additionally, there is a utility built into the OS that takes you to the right GitHub repository (page).

```
Open System Settings → About → Report a Problem
Choose the appropriate category and component
Follow the prompts to report a problem
```